# How to `pip install` from private GitHub releases?

Tags: github, pip, protocol-buffers, github-actions, python-packaging

I'm wondering if it's possible to `pip install` from "GitHub release assets" rather than from the source code of the corresponding GitHub tag of the release.

I can do `pip install` from a GitHub tag with no problem. However, I would like to install from the tag's corresponding release assets. I have the release asset packaged as `tar.gz` using GitHub Actions, but somehow I cannot point pip to install from the release asset.

The reason I need to install from the release asset is because I have "protobuf" generated classes that are not checked into the code base. Thus, the package generated using the source code on the GitHub tag is incomplete. I really don't want to check in the protobuf generated classes as they are machine generated.

Note that the GitHub repository is private.

Any idea how I could resolve this?

Comment: As far as I know it should be possible to use the direct URL to the `tar.gz` file.

Comment: Thanks @sinoroc. I'm using a private github repo and currently, I'm configuring a Github deployer key to access the repo. Thus directly using the http link to the `tar.gz` file doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Shouldn't the "protobuf generated classes" (whatever that is) be in the sdist (and the wheel)? Are those generated classes platform dependent (and/or dependent on the Python interpreter version, etc.)? -- I would assume that it is a solved issue already, and I am not sure what really is blocking you here... -- Question is vague and seems to lack the actually important details (as well as the fact that the repository is private)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer to the pip side of the question, but regarding Python and protobuf, I can share my experiences.

The typical way would be to generate the files during installation, from e.g. a call from `setup.py`. This does have some drawbacks though:

- It requires the `protoc` compiler during installation. It is easiest available from `grpcio-tools` Python package.
- The `protoc` version and `python-protobuf` library versions need to match. The `python-protobuf` project occassionally breaks compatibility of the generated files. In 2022, this happened in the 3.20.x -> 4.21.x [version transition](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/news/2022-05-06)

Because of the second point, if you choose to package the generated files, you need to also carefully set both minimum and maximum version of the `python-protobuf` dependency.

Comment: Thanks @jpa. I'm not quite familiar with the `setup.py` approach. I'm currently using `setup.cfg`. Do you have any link/suggestion how I can setup my build process to use `setup.py` instead? Thanks.

Comment: @WZH It seems that `setup.cfg` is preferred nowadays. There is probably some way to use custom build commands with it also.

Comment: You can have both a `setup.py` and a `setup.cfg`, and place everything but the custom commands in `setup.cfg`.